# Twitter User Details and Python

Tags: python, twitter

I'm a newby at using Python so excuse my ignorance but I have so far:

```
import twitter

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key="",
              consumer_secret="",
              access_token_key = "",
              access_token_secret = "")

handle = ('example')

user = api.GetUser(screen_name=handle)

print user.GetScreenName() 
print user.GetName()
print user.GetProfileImageUrl()
print user.GetDescription()
print user.GetCreatedAt()
print user.GetFollowersCount()
print user.GetFriendsCount()
print user.GetStatusesCount()
print user.GetFavouritesCount()
print user.GetLocation()
print user.GetTimeZone()
print user.GetLang()
print user.GetVerified()
```

which collects particular details about a particular user, however I need to collect multiple users details and this script only handles a single one per time.  id be really grateful if someone could help me figure out a way for the script to handle multiple handles to make my life a lot easier!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your printing into a function:

```
def printuser(user):
    # do all your printing
```

and have a list of multiple `handles`:

```
handles = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

then loop over it:

```
for handle in handles:
    printuser(api.GetUser(screen_name=handle))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a function that gets all the details you require, and then calling that function for multiple handles.

Something like:

```
def get_details(handle):
    user = api.GetUser(screen_name=handle)
    details = (user.GetScreenName(), user.GetName(), ..., user.GetVerified())
    dictionary = {handle: details}

list_of_handles = ['example', 'example2']
for name in list_of_handles:
    get_details(name)
```